# How to start an Android phone camera using a java code running on PC?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am developing a finger print scanning `JAVA` application for `Image Processing` using `OPENCV`. I thought of without using any scanner for this, I should do this using an `Android` phone camera. I which my `Java` Code will be starting the `android` camera and capturing an image and transferring directly it to the PC. I searched a lot but got no clue regarding it. All the clues are just like develop an `Android` application and stuff about it. Any help regarding this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a server that runs on the Android device and listens for messages sent from the PC. When a message is sent from the PC to the server (Like open camera for example) the Android device will start the camera app (Using an Intent )

Comment: How do I transfer that image to PC? @Charly1811

Comment: You can send a POST request to the server with the image as body

Comment: Thanks @Charly1811. I got it.